# Prove that the Euclid's parallel postulate is false on the hyperboloid model

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

Consider the two-dimensional case, i.e. of the hyperbolic place. Define our hyperboloid as the set of points  $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in 3-space (note: Minkowski space, but not needed for this problem) that fulfill $x_1^2 - y_1^2 - z_1^2 = 1$ and $x_1>0$. A hyperbolic line is defined as the intersection of a plane that goes through the origin with the hyperboloid. Two distinct hyperbolic points (points on the hyperboloid) determine a hyperbolic line. Consider the drawing labelled [2] on this picture for clarification (from [this](http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/us40_mode.htm) website):

[image: http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/fig22_21.gif]

I would like to prove something that seems intuitively clear:

> Given a hyperbolic line $h$ and a hyperbolic point $p$ not on $h$,
>   there are infinitely many hyperbolic lines through $p$ that do not
>   intersect $h$.

(note: this is the hyperbolic variant of Euclid's parallel postulate)

My attempt at a proof begins like this:

> We have by definition that $h$ is the intersection of the plane $m_1$
>   determined by two distinct hyperbolic points and the origin with the
>   hyperboloid. As $p$ is not contained by $h$, we have that $p$ cannot
>   be contained by $m_1$ either, so any hyperbolic line spanned by $p$ is
>   the intersection of a different plane $m_2$, determined by $p$, the
>   origin and some point $s$, with the hyperboloid. $m_1$ and $m_2$ are
>   thus distinct planes but because they meet at least at one point, the
>   origin, they cannot be parallel and hence we know from Euclidean
>   geometry that their intersection is a line $l$. Because $h$ is on the
>   hyperboloid, if $l$ and $h$ intersect it means that the hyperbolic
>   line spanned by $p$ intersects $h$ in a hyperbolic point, so we want
>   to show that there are infinite ways to choose the point $s$ so that
>   $h$ and $l$ do not intersect.

and at this point I was going to use a topological argument to show that we can select infinitely more points $s$ so that $h$ and $l$ do not intersect than not. But I could not do this, I think my method might be off and that algebra is a better way to go. Does anyone here know how to show this or can point me to a reference with a proof?

Comment: I do not know if this comes from a course and if there is more you have to do in the future regarding hyperbolic geometry. Here is a book I used when I took a course of non euclidean geometry (in which hyperbolic geometry forms a BIG topic): "Introduction to Non-Euclidean Geometry" by Harold Wolfe. Published by Dover Publications Inc. A very inexpensive book in which I remember your question is answered in great detail. I just can't come up with the right approach anymore. (Too long ago)

Comment: @imranfat My question is related to a paper that I'm writing for my university. I found a copy of this book, are you sure that the author discusses this in particular? I do not see any mention of the hyperboloid model and I do not find it in the index.

Comment: The book _Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry_ by Patrick Ryan treats hyperbolic geometry in your framework, and contains a proof that [Playfair's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair%27s_axiom) fails in the hyperbolic plane. (Can't give you an exact reference since I don't have the book at hand....)

Comment: @user86418 As far as I understand it, the parallel postulate (which is equivalent to Playfair's axiom in Euclid and Hilbert's framework) fails on the hyperbolic plane per definition, so what does Ryan prove? I am not so sure if this is relevant to my question since we do not know if there is hyperbolic geometry on the hyperboloid until we have proven this.

Comment: Ryan's approach is to show that $H$, the upper half of the hyperboloid in $\mathbf{R}^{2,1}$, with lines being intersections of $H$ with suitable planes, satisfies Euclid's first four axioms but not Playfair's. His proof that Playfair's axiom is false in this model amounts to what you're asking.

Comment: @user86418 Now I understand you, thank you for that. I found most of the book on Google Books: http://books.google.se/books/about/Euclidean_and_Non_Euclidean_Geometry.html?id=_6VoRV-RwNwC&redir_esc=y I did not see the proof here but it is possible that it is in an omitted chapter. If you know where in the book it is and you can see it there, please let me know, otherwise I'll try to find a copy of the book somewhere.

Comment: @user86418 I found the entire book on Cambridge University Press: http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511806209. Although the author discusses the hyperboloid model in detail, I find no mention of Playfair's axiom or anything like it and it is not in the index. Are you sure this is the right book? (and just so it's clear, I appreciate that you are helping me).

Comment: @Sid The book does deal with the hyperbolic surface even thoug it doesn't call it that way in the beginning. It makes the assumption of the parallel postulate that if through a point not on a line, infinite many parallel lines can be drawn, what kind of surface that would be. That turns out to be (chapters later) the hyperbolic surface. I thought (perhaps not so sure anymore) that was kind of what you were looking for...It continues to state that if there are no lines satisfying then it is a spherical surface although that is not the stretch of the book.

Comment: @Sid: My apology; you have the right book, but my memory was faulty about what Ryan states explicitly. Here's a sketch: The set of lines perpendicular to $h$ is a pencil of ultraparallels (Rmk. i, p. 156). For each such line $\ell$, there exists a unique line $\ell'$ through $p$ perpendicular to $\ell$ (Thm. 8 ii, p. 155); distinct $\ell$ give distinct $\ell'$ (else there would be a quadrilateral with four right angles). Since $\ell'$ and $h$ are ultraparallel (by Thm. 7, p. 155; both are perpendicular to $\ell$), they do not meet (Rmk. on p. 155).

Comment: @user86418 Thanks for your help, I will look into it. But I am a bit surprised about the sketch of your proof, since you assume that no quadrilaterals with four right angles exist. This is of course true in hyperbolic geometry as a consequence of the negation of the parallel postulate, but the negation of the parallel postulate is what we want to prove (or the hyperbolic axiom to be exact). So it sounds like we assume what we want to prove? Also, does this pertain to the hyperboloid model in particular?

Comment: Caveat: With no claim of elegance, the fact about quadrilaterals may be justified in Ryan's analytic model by looking at angular defects of hyperbolic triangles (Exercises 46-48, pp. 181-182). (But no, strictly this is not an argument using the hyperboloid model.:) This is rather blunt, but in the hyperboloid model, "an interval's worth" of planes (in $\mathbf{R}^{2,1}$) containing $p$ "clearly" do not intersect the line $h$, so the corresponding hyperbolic lines through $p$ do not hit $h$. Would making this argument more precise suit your aims?

Comment: @user86418 I appreciate your help but I do no see clearly how to make this argument rigorous enough. I honestly think now that this should be showed either by the idea suggested by user user126154 below or some difficult algebra (use the general equation for the plane that determines the hyperbolic line $h$, the equation for a plane determined by $p$, the origin and some point $s$ and show that there are infinite choices for $s$ so that no point $(x,y,z)$ of intersection of the two planes fulfills $x^2 = y^2+z^2$ and $x>0$ when $p$ is not on $h$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the projective model (or Klein model). That is to say, projectivise everythng:

For every line $l$ trough $0$ consider its intersection with the plane $\pi=\{x_1=1\}$. Every point of the hyperboloid is mapped to a point of the unit disc in $\pi$. Since the geodesic of the hyperbolic plane are intersections of the hyperboloid with planes through the origin, they project to usual segments in the disc, connecting two points of the boundary. Let's call them chords.

Now, in a disc it is easy to se that given a chord $r$ and a point $p$ not in $r$ there are infinitely many chords through $p$ that do not intersect $r$.

a complete reference for hyperbolic geometry is the book of Ratcliffe "Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds". There you find the projective model well descripted.

Comment: I have Ratcliffe's book (or do you mean "foundations of hyperbolic manifolds"? or is there another book I'm not aware of?), it's great but he does not go deep into axiomatics (and does not discuss this). Projecting onto the Klein model sounds interesting but when you do so, isn't it possible that the image of $p$ will be on the same line as the image of $h$ in the Klein model (if $p$ lies "beneath" $h$ on the hyperboloid for example)?

Comment: yes sure, is "manifolds" not "geometry". Have you solved your problem?

Comment: No I haven't, I haven't found the proof in the literature that's been suggested and I have not been able to construct a proof myself so far.

Comment: My answer is a proof: in the hyperboloid model, every point is determined by a line in $\mathbb R^3$ (trough the origin) and lines are intersection of $2$-planes with the hyperboloid. Now interserct everything with the plane $x_1=1$ and... as in the answer

Comment: I didn't see you had edited your answer, I understand you better now. So is there a bijection here, i.e. no two distinct points on the hyperboloid are mapped to the same point on the disc under your projection? If so then your solution works absolutely because it is very simple to show that the hyperbolic axiom is valid on the Klein model.

Comment: Yes, it is a bijection between the upper component of the hyperboloid (that with $x_1>0$) and the disk. This is easy to see because if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\lambda(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ you cannot have both $x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2=1=y_1^2-y_2^2-y_3^2$ unless $\lambda=\pm1$